# Why does the chosen user location impact the number of flights that Skyscanner returns?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I've noticed that the flight list that Skyscanner returns after a search depends on the chosen location (but not the currency, it seems). For example, in one of my searches, Skyscanner returned around 65 flights when the chosen location was US, and around 85 flights when the chosen location was UK. What could explain that difference?

User location choice:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right there, in Skyscanner regional settings box (when opened from a desktop browser):

[image]

I compared two search results for the same route and dates, the only difference was the country, and the different results in my case were with a local airline that seems to be offering local offers. One of the offers did not show when the location was the other country which was not the base country for the airline with the offer.

Comment: Thanks, good catch, I didn't try looking at the desktop version, only the mobile version and the Android app.

Comment: Follow-up question: [Why are some flight ticket deals localized?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178450/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt perhaps legal reasons, perhaps its a local agency that only operates within the country, etc.